Quarkus @Path disable url encoding
I have an endpoint on which I have plugged a restClient.
Via curl, I can upload a file as follows
curl "https://mydummyserver.com/api/v2/uploads.json?filename=order_issue.png" \
  --data-binary @order_issue.png \
  -H "Content-Type: image/png" \
  -X POST

So I wrote a restClient (Quarkus) in the following way.
@ApplicationScoped
@RegisterRestClient
public interface MyDummyService {

    @POST
    @Encoded
    @Path("/uploads.json?filename={filename}")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @ClientHeaderParam(name = "Content-Type", value = "{calculateContentType}")
    String uploadFile(
            @PathParam("filename") String filename,
            @NotBody String contentType,
            byte[] file);

    default String calculateContentType(ComputedParamContext context) {
        return context.methodParameters().get(1).value().toString();
    }
}

Snippet code is
String filePath = "order_issue.png";
byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(filePath)); 
String upload = myDummyService.uploadFile("order_issue.png", "image/png", bytes);

But something is wrong, the endpoint contains a ? and @Path encodes it. The endpoint contains a ? and @Path encodes it. And as the endpoint uploads.json%3Ffilename=order_issue.png is not recognized by the server, I get a 404 back
Is there a solution to disable URL encoding?
Some may recognize the Zendesk API ;)
Could you help me ?

Find a hack ?
I implement ClientRequestFilter as below
it's quite ugly, isn't it ?
@Provider
public class ConfigClientRequestFilter implements ClientRequestFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ClientRequestContext requestContext) {
        // @Path encode ? to %3F, so we need to decode it back to ?
        // Zendesk API does not accept %3F == Invalid Endpoint
        String pathInfo = requestContext.getUri().toString();
        URI myUri = null;
        try {
            myUri = new URI(pathInfo.replace("%3F", "?"));
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        requestContext.setUri(myUri);
    }
}

